# How to find roads on the image using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of aerial photography [Aerial Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VlAi.png).
I need to use OpenCV and Python to find roads on it. I used segmentation in HSV space to get rid of unnecessary parts of the picture, then I applied MorphologyEx and eventually got it [MorphologyEx Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66h97.png). What should I do next in order to find the right road in this image?

My Code:

```
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    imgHsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv.inRange(imgHsv, (21, 0, 0), (35, 225, 225))

    imask = mask > 0

    roads = np.zeros_like(frame, np.uint8)

    roads[imask] = frame[imask]

    #bluredRoadsMask = cv.medianBlur(roads, 7)
    grayRoads = cv.cvtColor(roads, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    phi = 1
    theta = 1
    maxIntensity = 255.0

    newImage = (maxIntensity/phi) * (grayRoads/(maxIntensity/theta))**2
    newImage = np.array(newImage, dtype=np.uint8)

    kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7, 7))
    # cross = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
    morphologyImg = cv.dilate(newImage, kernel, iterations=2)
    _, roadsThresh = cv.threshold(morphologyImg, 30, 225, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    gaus_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(roadsThresh, (5, 5), 3, 3)
    erodeImg = cv.erode(gaus_blur, kernel, iterations=1)
    morphExImage = cv.morphologyEx(erodeImg, cv.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)


    roadsEdges = cv.Canny(morphExImage, 0, 0, apertureSize= 3)


    lines = cv.HoughLinesP(roadsEdges, 0.05, np.pi / 180, 0, 40, 1)
    # for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    #     for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
    #         cv.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)


    # cv.imshow("roads", linesImage)
    cv.imshow("HSV Segmentation", morphExImage)
    # cv.imshow("grayFrame", gray)
    # cv.imshow("canny Edges", threshold)
    # cv.imshow("blur", bluredImage)
    cv.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
```

Thanks for answers!

upd: Use Hough Transform [Hough Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kACe2.png)

Comment: You could try to use Hough transform for line detection.

Comment: @SilverMonkey I tried to use Hough transform for line detection but in the end, I get a lot of lines if you know how to merge them I'd appreciate it

Comment: Try to calculate the length of the detected lines and discard lines below a certain threshold. This should get rid of the lines detected buildings/trees etc., but could also effect very short streets. You could then calculate the distance between the lines and merge lines which are in a certain proximity.

Comment: @SilverMonkey Thanks! I'll try to make it

Comment: Short addition: It would be also useful to take into account that the lines should not intersect before you merge them.